# How to get mysite url from Spuser

Tags: sharepoint-server

i can get all information about the user properties, but how could i get current users mysite url?

```
    Guid fieldID1 = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("UserNameField").Id;
                                    string valueField1 = item[fieldID1].ToString();

                                    SPFieldUserValue userField = (SPFieldUserValue)item.Fields[fieldID1].GetFieldValue(valueField1);

                                    SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(userField.User.ToString());
                                    SPList userInformationList = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
                                    SPListItem userItem = userInformationList.Items.GetItemById(user.ID);



                                    if (userItem["Title"] != null)
                                    {
                                        string name = userItem["Title"].ToString();

                                        Label1.Text = name;
                                        Label1.NavigateUrl =
                                        lblResponsible.Visible = true;


                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your solution in [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0dfc7e5f-a7c0-4439-86d6-1ba9690d65f8/how-to-get-users-my-site-url-using-visual-studio-2010-workflow-programmatically?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Referenced answer:

> Use as follows, make sure my site is present for the user.
>
> ```
> ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
> UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
> UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile('[user] name');
> string personUrl = profile.PersonalSite.Url;
> ```

Comment: Alright but my  UserProfileManager
UserProfile cant be find, its none reference like that?

Comment: You need to add reference of "Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles" dll from GAC to use UserProfileManager , UserProfile, etc.

Comment: What about Servercontext?

Comment: add reference of "Microsoft.Office.Server" :):)

Comment: TheRock, Please mark it as answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24204/discussion-between-kalpesh-vaghela-and-therock).